# How to optionally pass an parameter to django logging?

Tags: python, django, logging

In my django logging settings under formatter - I have a var:

```
%(new_line_number)s
```

I have a logging function in my views that calls logger.debug at the end, and so in this case I want to pass newlinenumber.

```
logger.debug('context for %s: %s', product, tool, extra={'newlinenumber':newlinenumber} )
```

I do NOT want to have to pass in extra={'newlinenumber':None} everytime I call the logger.  As that looks very messy and is redundant.  How can I accomplish this?  Currently if I do not include

```
extra={'newlinenumber':None}
```

The logger errors out anytime it has been called without newlinenumber.
The only time I am trying to pass in a newlinenumber is when I call it from my logging function.

Comment: Can you wrap the function, and just make the extra value you mentioned above the default

Comment: Um can you provide example?  I'm not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
def my_debug_function(my_str, product, tool, ext={'newlinenumber':None}):
    logger.debug(my_str, product, tool, extra=ext)
```

And then your usage would be `my_debug_function('content for %s, %s', product, tool)`

Here, I think I found something better...

```
def test_log(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwarg_defaults = {"extra": {"newlinenumber":None}}
    kwarg_defaults.update(kwargs)
    self.debug(*args, **kwarg_defaults)
```

the usage for this would be the same as whatever your debug is, but it's not limited to the 3 parameters that the other one was: `test_log('content for %s, %s', product, tool)`

It's risky modifying the original logger.debug, but if you're just pointing to it anyway, there shouldn't be too much of a problem...

you might say something along the following...

```
logger.old_debug = logger.debug
def test_log(*args, **kwargs):
    kwarg_defaults = {"extra": {"newlinenumber":None}}
    kwarg_defaults.update(kwargs)
    self.old_debug(*args, **kwarg_defaults)
logger.debug = test_log
```

Comment: I don't really know what exactly you're looking for, but this will at least solve that specific case.

Comment: I guess that will work, yea.  I was hoping there was a way to set a default newlinenumber if none is passed it.

Comment: Maybe that second one will be a bit more flexible for you.

Comment: the problem is that i would have to go through 10,000 lines of code and replace every logger.debug statement with a call to this function

Comment: every statement should be trivial with a find + replace, though I imagine it's a bit more complicated than that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173589/discussion-between-david-culbreth-and-david).